# REST API's for an existing rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I am creating RESTful API's for my existing rails app. In most of the examples I saw, I see that a new set of controllers are being created for API's. I was wondering if this is the best practice, cant I use my existing controllers and then have a new set of routes which re-direct here and expose the JSON output in the existing controllers. I am currently using rocket_pants.

Thanks a lot. I appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 1):

If your JSON api is just going to render existing resources as JSON then using the same controller to render different formats is a clean way to go. If your JSON api suddenly needs to fork from how you handle your other resources it can provide more flexibility to create separate controllers to manage the api. So, as with everything, there are some tradeoffs, but if you're sticking with a REST model I'd say just use the same controllers and offer up JSON formats.

Comment: Is there any resources online to learn adding api to existing controller ?

Comment: You can see the rails guides for handling different response formats: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#rendering-xml-and-json-data